# err-4058 npm not able to find a file

Tags: reactjs, node.js, terminal, npx

[image][image]

I have installed node js and also added the path
but when i try to create npx create-react-app it shows this error
do anyone knows this solution?

i wanted npx create-react-app to work.

// this is extra character just to doge stackoverflow conditions